# My $HOME/.magic magic number is not found

Tags: linux

I'm working on a software system on a Linux PC where a number of files will be 'typed' using magic numbers as described in the man pages: file(1) and magic(5). The system will have its own magic numbers, presumably stored in /usr/share/misc/magic, but that is not the issue at this point. At this time, I'm just trying to get a prototype working and then I hope to progress from there.

My problem is that I think I am following the manpage directions, but when I run:

```
file hello
```

I am not getting the results that I expect. The output is the standard ELF message, but I'm expecting to be able to override the default message with my own.

What I have done so far:

1. Created `$HOME/.magic` with a single line that is described below.
2. Created hello.c:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   main() {
            printf("Hello, World\n");
   }
   ```
3. Compiled with:

   ```
   cc -o hello hello.c
   ```
4. Octal dump in hex format with:

   ```
   od -h hello | head -1
   ```

   that gives the output:

   ```
   0000000 457f 464c 0102 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
   ```

   and note that the first byte of the file is hex value '457f'.
5. Reading manpage magic(5), I create the line for my .magic file:

   ```
   0     byte       0x457f        "executable: This file is an ELF file."
   ```

My understanding of the fields is:

```
0 - Zero offset from the beginning of the file
byte - The magic number is being handdled at byte(s)
0x457f - This is the expected value of the first byte of the file, i.e. the byte with 0 offset from the start of the file.
executable: This file is an ELF file. - The message that is printed when the file command finds a file with the 0x457f magic number
```

With these tasks done, I then run my file command:

```
file hello
```

As mentioned, this command gives me the standard output for an ELF file, not my modified version.

According to the file(1) manpage, the $HOME/.magic file takes precedence over the /usr/share/misc/magic (or magic.mgc) file/directory. Thus, even though the default magic number is defined, my .magic file should override.

At this point, I'm experimenting to try to find what I'm doing wrong. For example, maybe my format in the .magic file is incorrect.

I have looked for example .magic files on the internet, but so far I have not found any. Interestingly, I have found a number of documents on how to use 'file', but in none of them have I found a working example using a local .magic file.

Any advice or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: 0x457f is not a byte, it's a short. For .magic syntax use `man magic`, there is a lot of examples. You can also read standard magic file.

Comment: Well, I guess I did things right. After I sent out this question, I sat down to experiment some more. I made no changes and ran my test: 'file hello' and to my suprise, it worked!

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunes - Thanks, for the short comment - I should have caught that. When I run 'man magic', I get magic(5). I assume this is what you mean.

Comment: Use code formatting (just like you did for `hello.c`) to show the contents of the file without reformatting the whitespace.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks - Will do in the future.